# Share link in social auth app on click without login in android?

Tags: android, share, socialauth

I want to share a link in social auth through the dialog box. How can I achieve it without login in to the app

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH19V.png).

Answer (score 0):

check it for solution and may be helpful to youhttp://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/get-social-using-android-intents-to-share-a-link/